# Why I can do a wildcard copy from one location, but can't from another?

Tags: batch, wildcard, cp

One wildcard batch copy works for me:

```
sudo cp /home/jenkins/dist/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/
```

but another similar doesn't:

```
sudo cp /opt/tomcat/webapps/*.war /home/jenkins/archive
cp: cannot stat '/opt/tomcat/webapps/*.war': No such file or directory
```

But actually both folders have that sort of files:

```
sudo ls -l /opt/tomcat/webapps/
total 330536
drwxr-x--- 5 tomcat paysoft      4096 Sep 26 02:12 ROOT
-r-x------ 1 tomcat tomcat  127981631 Sep 26 02:10 ROOT.war
drwxr-x--- 4 root   root         4096 Feb 26  2023 site-api
-r-x------ 1 tomcat tomcat  106277537 Sep 26 02:11 site-api.war
drwxr-x--- 4 tomcat paysoft      4096 Sep 26 02:11 web-api
-r-x------ 1 tomcat tomcat  104181448 Sep 26 02:11 web-api.war
```

and

```
sudo ls -l /home/jenkins/dist/
total 569312
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 112948432 Aug  1  2022 money-transfer-web.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 127981631 Sep 26 02:03 ROOT.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 106277537 Sep 26 02:03 site-api.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 131561362 Sep 26 02:03 terminal-server.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 104181448 Sep 26 02:03 web-api.war
```

what is the reason?

P.S. The directories themselves are:

```
sudo ls -l /home/jenkins/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Jul 11 15:20 archive
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun 30  2022 dist
```

Comment: I see a permissions difference that may be important... but what are permissions for the directories? If the tomcat webapps directory does not have the `x` flag set, directory search would not be permitted, and that might be why `cp` can't look for files in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sudo cp /home/jenkins/dist/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/

Here, your (non-privileged) shell will attempt to expand the '*' before passing the resulting command line to sudo - hence its behaviour will depend on your permissions to read from /home/jenkins/dist/.

You didn't show us what the permissions were on the directories - only their contents.

Conversely in the following case, the expansion is done by the root shell:

```
sudo 'cp /home/jenkins/dist/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/'
```

Comment: Hi! I have updted the question with ls -l of the directories. Could you check now, please?

Comment: That `ls` is useless, since you ran it with `sudo` again. The point is, that the shell tries to expand the path **before** sudo is invoked, which most probably fails. Also, it was run on the wrong directory. `sudo namei -l /opt/tomcat/webapps/` would shed some light on this.

Comment: @symcbean you accidently swapped the paths, your examples use the path where it worked, not where it didn't.